# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:proiectP.JavatoC.getval(I)I

Tags: java, c, dll, path

This is my code and i have added the .dll to the place where Java_Home is. And i have this error:

> ***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: proiectP.JavatoC.getval(I)I       at proiectP.JavatoC.getval(Native
>   Method)     at proiectP.JavatoC.main(JavatoC.java:19)***

```java
public class JavatoC {
    public native int getval(int b);
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("main");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int a;
            int b=3;
            a= new JavatoC().getval(b); 
            System.out.println(a);     
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to write `a= new proiectP.JavatoC().getval(b)` as *proiectP* is the package. It doesn't work.

Comment: Just guessing, perhaps you are trying to use a 32-bit native interface DLL with a 64-bit Java runtime, or vice versa?

Comment: Initially i made that mistake and told me exactly that was the mistake but now I have installed a 32-bit JDK and i did not have anymore that error, but the one I told you. And the Jdk is on 32-bit.

Answer (score 7):

It seems library link not done right. There is a problem in the System.loadLibrary. Because it can't show the required method.

These are requirements for using a native code in Java, And I don't know which has not been observed :

First, make sure that the native file is correct, the getval method must be in that dll, exactly with the same specifications of name, input and output.

Second, it is exactly compiled for this use.

The last is in the right direction with the right name.